# How to debug phonegap javascript application on visual studio 2012 emulator

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to run my application on windows 8 phone visual studio emulator but seems like some error in my code. But i am not able to debug the java script code.

Is there any way to debug the code through emulator?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSConsole](http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html) or [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) (which is BTW also a part of Cordova). You inject a line of code into your JavaScript, which connects to a console on another computer.

Actually, seems someone already made it easy: http://debug.phonegap.com/ (using weinre)